# Nothing visible on MacBook Air screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

my MacBook screen is completely covered with these vertical lines and I can’t see anything on screen. About a week back 75% screen was covered in horizontal lines and I could only work in small horizontal space on the upper side of the screen. It got okay on its own and now I opened the laptop today and found entire screen covered.
Have tried option+cmnd+r+p.

[image]

Comment: A picture would help, but it sounds like either a display cable or screen issue. If you could take a photo & compare it to a screen capture, that could eliminate a software issue as the cause [but that's going to be tough if you can't see enough of the screen to use it].

Comment: Can’t see anything and pictur added

Comment: I think it's time to take it to a repair shop.